# Extract text from brackets

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, grep

I have a file like this:

## input file:

```
Evigen1000005_c0_g1_i1  0.240   1.212   1.408   3.784   2.029   0.963   -1.22409810298695       1       NA      NA      NA      NA      PF04597.13;Ribophorin_I;4.6e-148        NA      1;21;0.875      len=569;ExpAA=32.49;First60=12.82;PredHel=1;Topology=o433-450i     Q9SFX3  OST1A_ARATH     reviewed        Dolichyl-diphosphooligosaccharide--protein_glycosyltransferase_subunit_1A_(EC_2.4.99.18)_(Ribophorin_IA)_(RPN-IA)_(Ribophorin-1A)  OST1A_RPN1A_At1g76400_F15M4.10  Arabidopsis_thaliana_(Mouse-ear_cress)  614     protein_N-linked_glycosylation_via_asparagine_[GO:0018279]      endoplasmic_reticulum_[GO:0005783];_integral_component_of_membrane_[GO:0016021];_membrane_[GO:0016020];_oligosaccharyltransferase_complex_[GO:0008250]     dolichyl-diphosphooligosaccharide-protein_glycotransferase_activity_[GO:0004579]        3702.AT1G76400.1;  PF04597;        IPR007676;      3702    ath:AT1G76400;  F15M4.10        2.4.99.18       SUBCELLULAR_LOCATION:_Endoplasmic_reticulum_membrane_{ECO:0000250};_Single-pass_type_I_membrane_protein_{ECO:0000250}.  SIGNAL_1_25_{ECO:0000255}. AT1G76400.1;    NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA 
Evigen1000006_c0_g1_i1  0.358   0.179   0.000   0.424   0.139   0.183   NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      PF07767.10;Nop53_(60S_ribosomal_biogenesis);5.2e-21     NA      1;31;0.588      len=170;ExpAA=14.33;First60=14.27;PredHel=0;Topology=o     O22892  NOP53_ARATH     reviewed        Ribosome_biogenesis_protein_NOP53       At2g40430_T2P4.22       Arabidopsis_thaliana_(Mouse-ear_cress)  442     ribosomal_large_subunit_assembly_[GO:0000027];_ribosomal_large_subunit_export_from_nucleus_[GO:0000055]    nucleolus_[GO:0005730];_nucleoplasm_[GO:0005654]        rRNA_binding_[GO:0019843]       3702.AT2G40430.2;       PF07767;   IPR011687;      3702    ath:AT2G40430;  T2P4.22 SUBCELLULAR_LOCATION:_Nucleus,_nucleolus_{ECO:0000250|UniProtKB:Q9NZM5}._Nucleus,_nucleoplasm_{ECO:0000250|UniProtKB:Q9NZM5}.   AT2G40430.1_[O22892-1]; NA NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

I want to take out the text form the brackets which only starts with "GO:". After each GO: there are 7 digits. e.g. "GO:0018279". They are GO terms. The number of GO terms in each row are not equal. The output must be a file which the first column includes the Untranscript ids (e.g. Evigen1000005_c0_g1_i1) and the rest GO terms. I want an output file like this:

## output file:

```
Evigen1000005_c0_g1_i1 GO:0018279 GO:0005783 GO:0016021 GO:0016020 GO:0008250 GO:0004579
Evigen1000006_c0_g1_i1 GO:0000027 GO:0000055 GO:0005730 GO:0005654 GO:0019843
```

Comment: Should [GO:0016021] and [O22892-1] be excluded from the output? In that case why? Please specify in detail how to select the output!

Comment: yes, it should excluded

Comment: If you explain why to exclude these data (what makes them 'wrong'), it should be possible to design a method to exclude them automatically. Otherwise we can only guess or leave the exclusion to manual methods.

Comment: the text presented in brackets started with GO: were Gene Ontology for each Unitranscrit (e.g. Evigen1000005_c0_g1_i1), to do GO category with WEGO tool we need a file which the first column is Untranscript ids and the rest GO terms.

Comment: OK. So [O22892-1] should be excluded. What about  [GO:0016021]?

Comment: no, it should not be extended. there a mistake in the output file. I edit the output file.

Comment: Thanks! I think everything is explained and understood now, and you can go ahead and use the script as it is :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested `script`, that matches your final specification.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
# echo "$line"
 name=${line%% *}
 echo -n "$name "
 data=$(<<< "$line" grep -o '\[GO:.\{7\}\]' | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -e 's/\[//g' -e 's/\]//g')
 echo "$data"
done < "$1"
```

Testing:

```
$ ./script input 
Evigen1000005_c0_g1_i1 GO:0018279 GO:0005783 GO:0016021 GO:0016020 GO:0008250 GO:0004579 
Evigen1000006_c0_g1_i1 GO:0000027 GO:0000055 GO:0005730 GO:0005654 GO:0019843
```

Comment: @Mehdi, You are welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
sed -r 's/(^[^[:space:]]* )[^[]*\[/\1/; s/\][^[]*(\[|$)/ /g' file
Evigen1000005_c0_g1_i1 GO:0018279 GO:0005783 GO:0016021 GO:0016020 GO:0008250 GO:0004579 
Evigen1000006_c0_g1_i1 GO:0000027 GO:0000055 GO:0005730 GO:0005654 GO:0019843 O22892-1
```

Your desired output does NOT reflect the processed input sample.

**EDIT:** or even

```
sed -r 's/((^[^ ]* )|\])[^[]*(\[|$)/\2 /g' file
```

**EDIT:** with your question and desired output three times revised, try

```
sed -r 's/((^[^ ]* )|\])[^[]*(\[GO)/\2 GO/g; s/\].*$//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Faster in sed:

```
start='\[GO:' end='\]'
sed -e 's,'"$start"$',\1,g' -e 's,'"$end"$',\2,g' \
    -e $'s, [^\1]*, ,' -e $'s,\1\\([^\2]*\\)\2[^\1]*,GO:\\1 ,g' \
    infile
```

or awk:

```
awk -vone=$'\1' -vtwo=$'\3' -vstart='\[GO:' -v end='\]' '
           {
            printf("%s ",$1);
            gsub(start,one);
            gsub(end,two);
            sub("^[^"one"]*"one,"GO:")
            gsub(two"[^"one"]*"one," GO:")
            sub(two".*$" ,"")
           }
           1' infile
```